# tm_map function in R tm package changing aspects when calling on corpus

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I had run some basic text processing using tm and other packages in R a few months ago. I'm trying to call a specific document from a corpus, which works just fine prior to doing any cleaning using tm_map. However, after running a function to clean the text, it tries to display text for all documents and bogs down my whole R system. Any suggestions? Did some underlying aspect of tm change to where this syntax no longer applies? Example data and syntax below:

```
#data#
file = as.data.frame(matrix( c('case1', 'this is some SAMPLE TEXT!','case2',  'and this is the 2nd version of that text...'), 
            nrow=2,              
            ncol=2,              
            byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(file) [1] <- 'doc_id'
names(file) [2] <- 'text'
print (file)

library(tm)
wordCorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(file))
wordCorpus[[1]][1] #as expected, shows one document#
wordCorpus[[1]]$content #as expected, shows one document#
wordCorpus[[2]][1] #as expected, shows one document#
wordCorpus[[2]]$content #as expected, shows one document#
str(wordCorpus)

#clean the text#
custom_stopwords <-  c( "the") #creating custom stopword list#

word_fixer <- function(x) {
  x <- 
    gsub("every day", "everyday",x)
  return(x)
}
word_fixer ("I love it every day... oops meant everyday")


#Cleaning function#
clean_corpus <- function (wordCorpus) {
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removeNumbers)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removePunctuation)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer (word_fixer))
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removeWords, custom_stopwords)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, stripWhitespace)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
  return (wordCorpus)
}
#Putting cleaner to work#
wordCorpus <- clean_corpus (wordCorpus)
wordCorpus[[1]][1] #now it shows both documents#
wordCorpus[[2]][1]
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting from this? It seems to return the same thing for me. Tested with `tm_0.7-1`

Comment: tm_0.7-3. It should read ""this is some SAMPLE TEXT!", which it does prior to the tm_map. After the tm map, it reads "this is some sample text"            "and this is nd version of that text" . I don't recall ever having this issue prior to updating to newer version to tm, which I just did recently

Comment: Whey do you have the line `wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, PlainTextDocument)`? That seems to be what's messing things up. Just take it out.

Comment: I thought this was required to treat the text as documents. I had toggled through all the sub-cleaning options and that was the only I didn't try, but you are correct, it does solve the issue. Odd. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick - So somewhat related question dealing with apparent changes to tm. This line below would work to create unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams. However, this no longer function in that. Any knowledge of this not converting to new tm version.                                                        
     tokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, 
    max = 3))

    dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix (wordCorpus, control = list 
    (tokenize=tokenizer))

Comment: I found a solution to the above by using "VCorpus" instead of "Corpus". It is an odd bug with recent updates